# How to remove duplicate from list of tuple

Tags: python, tuples

How to remove duplicate from this tuple when the field#2 (f#2) are identical except for field1 (f#1)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
group = (#f#1        f#2
        (1658, 'alps no shoujo heidi'),
        (1659, 'alps no shoujo heidi'),
        (1660, 'alps no shoujo heidi'),
        (1661, 'alps no shoujo heidi'),
        (1662, 'alps no shoujo heidi'),
        (1663, 'alps no shoujo heidi'),
)

titles = list(dict.fromkeys(group))
print(titles)
```

I'm trying to get this output:

> (1663, 'alps no shoujo heidi')
>
> or
>
> (1658, 'alps no shoujo heidi')

Comment: So... which of those outputs are you looking for? `(1663, 'alps no shoujo heidi')` or `(1658, 'alps no shoujo heidi')`? What about `(1659, 'alps no shoujo heidi')`? Why should one be preferred over the others?

Comment: @Chris I think that it just needs to return the first or last found tuple.

Comment: @MarcelloZago, we shouldn't have to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an approach where you can reduce the list by saving all Strings that have been encountered before:

```
already_found = []
reduced_group = []
for item in group:
    if item[1] not in already_found:
        already_found.append(item[1])
        reduced_group.append(item)


print(reduced_group)
```

This way you will always keep the first tuple that contains a duplicated String.

Answer (score 0):

Your current use case to get only one element-

```
group = (#f#1        f#2
        (1658, 'alps no shoujo heidi'),
        (1659, 'alps no shoujo heidi'),
        (1660, 'alps no shoujo heidi'),
        (1661, 'alps no shoujo heidi'),
        (1662, 'alps no shoujo heidi'),
        (1663, 'alps no shoujo heidi'),
)

titles = list(dict.fromkeys({t[1]: t for t in group}.values()))
print(titles[0])
```

**Output**

```
(1663, 'alps no shoujo heidi')
```

**Use Case 2:**

```
group = (#f#1        f#2
        (1658, 'alps no shoujo heidi1'),
        (1659, 'alps no shoujo heidi2'),
        (1660, 'alps no shoujo heidi3'),
        (1661, 'alps no shoujo heidi1'),
        (1662, 'alps no shoujo heidi2'),
        (1663, 'alps no shoujo heidi4'),
)

titles = list(dict.fromkeys({t[1]: t for t in group}.values()))
print(titles)
```

**Outout**

```
[(1661, 'alps no shoujo heidi1'), (1662, 'alps no shoujo heidi2'), (1660, 'alps no shoujo heidi3'), (1663, 'alps no shoujo heidi4')]
```